# How Can I get value from GridView_RowUpdating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
Public Function GridView_RowUpdating(sender As Object, _ 
                                e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) As    Integer

    Dim ID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value
    Return ID

End Function
```

I need the id(datakey) for edit data from myGridview on another page. How can I do it?

Comment: What is it that you are exactly trying to do? The question is not clear enough.

Comment: i want to update data when i click update link in gridview. i build another webpage for editing data

Comment: @user3534404: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take sometime to edit your question by adding more details. Add things like, what is your exact requirement? what have you done so far? where are you stuck at? Are you trying to open a new EditDetails page when one clicks on the edit link in the `GridViewRow`?

Comment: try to use request.querystring and transfer your key to edit page and retrieve regarding data for edit.

Comment: i want to update data when i click update link in gridview. i build another webpage for editing data // for example                     Dim db as SampleEntity()                                            Dim obj = db.tblCustomer.First(Function(x) x.ID = ID)       obj.Customer = Customer.Text                             db.SaveChange()   //Gridview is on Webform1 and Editpage is on Webform 2

Answer (score 2):

chk this code will help you....

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdViewTracking" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true"
                        OnSorting="grdViewTracking_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="#E7E7E7"
                        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" OnPageIndexChanging="grdViewTracking_PageIndexChanging"
                        CellPadding="1" ForeColor="#666666" PageSize="10" Width="100%">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr style="background-color: White">
                                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Number")%>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key" SortExpression="Key" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="PaddingLeft5" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr style="background-color: White">
                                            <td style="padding-left: 5px">
    ***<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkkey" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key")%>'></asp:LinkButton>***

                                                <input type=hidden runat="server"   id="hfid" value=' <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Appsettingid")%>' />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

below code to transfer control to second page i.e. edit page.....

```
protected void grdViewTracking_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            BusinessLogicPOS.AppSettingArgs ob = e.Row.DataItem as BusinessLogicPOS.AppSettingArgs;
            LinkButton lnkkey = e.Row.FindControl("lnkkey") as LinkButton;
            lnkkey.PostBackUrl = "AppSetting.aspx?AppSettingId=" + ob.AppSettingId.ToString();
        }
```

Check reference:

[example](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-send-gridview-row-values-to.html)

Comment: if answer is useful thn please accept it as right answer for other user understanding and upvote it

Comment: thanx for posting the link its really useful to new user to understand the system and encourage them to contribute more and solve the question so it will help other.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this will be like this.

At WebForm1 markup use either of these two methods

a. Use a `asp:TemplateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="EditLink" runat="server" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# "~/WebForm2.aspx?id=" + Eval("ID") %>'
                Text="Update" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

b. Use a `asp:HyperLinkField`

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Update"
    DataNavigateUrlFields="ID"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\WebForm2.aspx?id={0}"          
    HeaderText="Action" />
```

And at WebForm2 code-behind do this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim passedID As String = Request.QueryString("id")
            'populate the fields using .FirstOrDefault
        Else
            'no id passed. cannot process
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much mr.naveen it's very helpful